# Ubuntu 18.04: EXT4-fs (sda1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, disk

Ubuntu 18.04 auto boots into emergency mode for some reason, and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it returns the following error:

> EXT4-fs (sda1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem.

I also formatted an EXTERNAL drive to exfat and edited fstab after that.
Weirdly enough, if I turn off the system it boots normally.

```
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0 118.8G  0 part /
sdc      8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 931.5G  0 part /media/exfat
zsh: command not found: tempfs
```

Comment: When you power off then power back up and get back into Ubuntu, please run _lsblk | grep -v "loop"  && df -h | grep -v loop|tempfs_ and copy the resulting text. Then, come back here, click [edit] and paste that text into your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Ok I tried that command out, but tempfs didn't work